# selection theory for normal non-paracompact domains?

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, selection-principles

Are there theorems in selection theory without either paracompactness or convexity assumptions ?
That is, a theorem that claims existence of selections for any (perfectly or hereditary) normal spaces, and does not assume convexity of values.

If I understand correctly, what is used in selection theory
is paracompactness implies decomposition of unity.